# pyspark.SparkSession: how to set Hadoop config directory from Python code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I want to create a `pyspark.SparkSession` to read a Hive base want to import Hive settings from config directory (with `hive-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, etc).

I don't want to set `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable before run, because I need to read data from different Hadoop clusters with different settings (settings XML files for each cluster are present on my local FS).

How can I say `SparkSession.builder` in which folder to look for configs from Python code?